# How do I prove tight bound

Tags: asymptotics

I have a recurrence relation:

T(n)=   3T(n-1)-2T(n-2) Where n>1 .

note when 1, n=1. and when  0, n=0  .

Find a tight bound for T(n). How do I now prove that it's big O and Ω in order to prove it's tight bound

Not really sure how to solve this.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Note that $3T(n-1) > T(n) > 3(T(n-1)-T(n-2))$. Now, use these bounds to make a conclusion.

Comment: Show your attempt. What have you tried? What do you think?

Comment: Why not just solve the linear recurrence in this particular case?

Comment: This is a linear recurrence.  Look to the characteristic polynomial of the recurrence, which in this case is $x^2-3x+2=0$.  Factor that to find $(x-2)(x-1)$ which implies that $T(n)=a\cdot 2^n + b\cdot 1^n$ for some specific values of $a$ and $b$ which are dependent on the initial conditions.

Comment: If the initial conditions are $T(1)=1$ and $T(0)=0$ then you have $T(n)=2^n-1$

Comment: yes I solved in order to prove by induction and I got T(n)=2^n−1. I'm not sure how to improve tight bound

Comment: Well if you ask me $T(n)\leq 2^n -1$ is a very tight bound but I don't know.

Comment: Once you determined that $T(n) = 2^n - 1$ it trivially follows that $T(n) = \Theta(2^n)$ i.e. both $\mathcal {O}$ and $\Omega$.

Comment: @dxiv So I don't need to prove that ? or how it's equal to  Big O and Ω

Comment: $lim_{n \to \infty} T(n) / 2^n = 1$ implies (and is in fact stronger than) $T(n) = \Theta(2^n)$. What parts precisely you have to prove depends on what you know already and are allowed to use, which I can't guess.